# If/Else based on existence of object in array?

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, uitableview

I want to trigger an else statement if there is no object at the indexPath i look for in an array.

The array is

```
let exerciseSets = unsortedExerciseSets.sorted { ($0.setPosition < $1.setPosition) }
```

Then i use `let cellsSet = exerciseSets[indexPath.row]`

There is a chance, when a user is adding a new cell, that it wont already have an exerciseSet at the indexPath to populate it (adding a new set to an existing array of sets) and so I need to run an else statement to set up a blank cell rather than attempting to populate it and crashing my app.

However if i use if let then i get this error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not
>   'UserExerciseSet'

Here is the whole function for context if needed:

```
    func configure(_ cell: NewExerciseTableViewCell, at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if self.userExercise != nil {
        print("RESTORING CELLS FOR THE EXISTING EXERCISE")
        let unsortedExerciseSets = self.userExercise?.exercisesets?.allObjects as! [UserExerciseSet]
        let exerciseSets = unsortedExerciseSets.sorted { ($0.setPosition < $1.setPosition) }

        if let cellsSet = exerciseSets[indexPath.row] { // this causes a creash when user adds new set to existing exercise as it cant populate, needs an else statement to add fresh cell
            cell.setNumber.text = String(cellsSet.setPosition)
            cell.repsPicker.selectRow(Int(cellsSet.setReps), inComponent: 0, animated: true)

            let localeIdentifier = Locale(identifier: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "locale") as! String)
            let setWeight = cellsSet.setWeight as! Measurement<UnitMass>
            let formatter = MassFormatter()
            formatter.numberFormatter.locale = localeIdentifier
            formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

            if localeIdentifier.usesMetricSystem {
                let kgWeight = setWeight.converted(to: .kilograms)
                let finalKgWeight = formatter.string(fromValue: kgWeight.value, unit: .kilogram)
                let NumericKgResult = finalKgWeight.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted)
                cell.userExerciseWeight.text = NumericKgResult
            } else {
                let lbsWeight = setWeight.converted(to: .pounds)
                let finalLbWeight = formatter.string(fromValue: lbsWeight.value, unit: .pound)
                let NumericLbResult = finalLbWeight.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted)
                cell.userExerciseWeight.text = NumericLbResult
            }

        } else {
            cell.setNumber.text = String((indexPath.row) + 1)
        }
```

Comment: yes but that isnt a solution to the question

Comment: Its about solving the issue, the error was just an indication of the obstacle i face with this method, you just reiterated the error i have as opposed to an alternate solution to resolve it, which is ideally what i came here for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something crazy like this:

```
if let cellSet = (indexPath.row < exerciseSets.count ? exerciseSets[indexPath.row] : nil) {
    //
}
```

but it would be more straightforward to do:

```
if indexPath.row < exerciseSets.count {
    let cellSet = exerciseSets[indexPath.row]
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks you submitted this solution first and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

OK, so your problem is that you are trying to access a value in an array that may or may not be there.

If you just try to access the value based on `indexPath` you can crash because `indexPath` may refer to a value not there. On the other hand, the array does not return an optional so you can't use `if let` either.

I kind of like the idea of using an optional, so how about introducing a function that could return an optional to you if it was there.

Something like:

```
func excerciseSet(for indexPath: IndexPath, in collection: [UserExcerciseSet]) -> UserExcerciseSet? {
    guard collection.count > indexPath.row else {
        return nil
    }
    return collection[indexPath.row]
}
```

and then you can say:

```
if let cellsSet = exerciseSet[for: indexPath, in: excerciseSets] {  
    //It was there...showtime :)
} else {
    cell.setNumber.text = String((indexPath.row) + 1)
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the index against your array count:

```
if indexPath.item < exerciseSets.count {

    // Cell exists
    let cellsSet = exerciseSets[indexPath.row]

} else {
    // cell doesn't exists. populate new one
}
```